# Normal Distribution given a Probability Inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution

Given  $ Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0.3, 0.7) $. Calculate $P(|Y − 0.2| < 0.8)$.

---

This looks fairly simple, but I'm confused on which formula to use. I know that $$P(|X − \mu| < c) \le \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{c^2}$$

But the $\mu$ in $ Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0.3, 0.7) $ is 0.3, while the $\mu$ in the inequality is 0.2. Does this matter?  Since to find $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ i would just have to take square 0.7 from $ Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0.3, 0.7) $ ? Is $\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{c^2}$ the solution or should I go onto trying to find a Normal Distribution?

Comment: Is your goal to find a bound or to solve for the probability?

Comment: I'm assuming to solve for the probability. What I typed is in verbatim of the problem I was given.

Comment: Is that Chebyshev's inequality? I believe your direction of inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. $P(|Y-a| < b) = P(a - b < Y < a + b)$ and
2. $Z = (Y-\mu) / \sigma$ is standard normal where $\mu = 0.3$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{0.7}$.

Comment: Oh! So I get the bounds for Y and those become my Y-bounds in Z?

Comment: @Deegeeek: yes and then you use your tables ... or wolfram alpha :D